# Django form placeholder and label is not translated after activating arabic translation

Tags: python, django, forms

I am new to django and tried every solution on the internet but nothing worked.

I am developing a website in arabic and english using django

The problem is when I created a form and load the website in arabic the form is not translated to arabic I mean placeholders, labels and errors.

the code to switch english to arabic template and vice versa

```
def to_arabic(request, url):
    translation.activate('ar')
    return redirect('/ar' + url)

def to_english(request, url):
    translation.activate('en')
    return redirect('/' + url[4:])
```

The form code

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class ContactUsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=50, min_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('username'), 'autofocus': ''}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=80, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('email')}))
    subject = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=50, min_length=2, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('subject')}))
    message = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=500, min_length=10, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': _('message')}))
```

in the template I loaded the i18n tag

```
{% load i18n %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

translation.activate('ar') must be written in the view before rendering the html template or to use sessions.